# inno setup.exe fails with Floating point division by zero on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, inno-setup

I have setup an inno setup script that installs my application.  The resulting setup.exe will install properly on windows vista/7 but fails with the division by zero error on windows xp. The inno example scripts work on windows xp so it must be something I am doing.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
#define app_src_path "..\MyApp"
#define app_exe_path "..\bin"

#define file_ver GetFileVersion(app_exe_path + "\win32\MyApp.exe")
#define app_ver Delete(file_ver, 6, 2)

[Setup]
AppId={{BBB40316-958C-446B-A08D-311273214AA6}
AppName=MyApp
AppVersion={#app_ver}
UninstallDisplayName=MyApp
AppPublisher=My Company US
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Company\MyApp
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName=My Company
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
#emit 'OutputBaseFilename="MyApp-Setup-' + app_ver + '"'
#emit 'SetupIconFile="' + app_src_path + '\rc\MyAppIcon.ico"'
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
WizardImageFile=ZDS.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=ZDSsmall.bmp

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[InstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\MyApp";

[Files]
; x64 files
Source: "{#app_exe_path}\x64\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: Is64BitInstallMode

; win32 files
Source: "{#app_exe_path}\win32\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode

; platform independent
Source: "{#app_src_path}\rc\pic1-24.png"; DestDir: "{app}\rc"; Flags: ignoreversion nocompression
Source: "{#app_src_path}\rc\pic2-24.png"; DestDir: "{app}\rc"; Flags: ignoreversion nocompression
Source: "{#app_src_path}\rc\pic3-24.png"; DestDir: "{app}\rc"; Flags: ignoreversion nocompression

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,MyApp}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,MyApp}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

**EDIT:** 
Here is the output from the /LOG

```
2012-07-14 10:07:50.855   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-04:00)
2012-07-14 10:07:50.855   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.1 (u)
2012-07-14 10:07:50.855   Original Setup EXE: E:\MyApp-Setup-0.0.0.exe
2012-07-14 10:07:50.855   Setup command line: /SL5="$801DE,623918,137216,E:\MyApp-Setup-0.0.0.exe" /LOG
2012-07-14 10:07:50.855   Windows version: 5.1.2600 SP3  (NT platform: Yes)
2012-07-14 10:07:50.855   64-bit Windows: No
2012-07-14 10:07:50.870   Processor architecture: x86
2012-07-14 10:07:50.870   User privileges: Administrative
2012-07-14 10:07:50.885   Exception message:
2012-07-14 10:07:50.885   Message box (OK):
                          Floating point division by zero.
2012-07-14 10:07:51.654   User chose OK.
2012-07-14 10:07:51.654   Deinitializing Setup.
2012-07-14 10:07:51.654   Log closed.
```

I don't have a [code] section so I am confused where the MessageBox (OK) message is originating from.

Comment: What version of InnoSetup are you using?  What version of XP are you using?  At what point during the install do you get the division by zero error?

Comment: inno-setup 5.5.1(u) and windows xp sp3 both 32 and 64 bit.  The setup fails immediately upon starting it with a dialog box saying Floating point division by zero.  It never brings up the starting install page.

Comment: Well, there's nothing obvious in that script snippet that could cause that. Do you have any [Code]? Have you tried using /LOG?
Also, you should probably replace those #emit lines with regular lines that use {#app_ver} etc. It's much tidier.

Comment: I noticed that the output name is MyApp-Setup-0.0.0.exe.  Can you recompile your application with a non-zero version (even if it's just 1.0.0).  I don't think it's a problem but that's the only thing I can think of.  I compiled your script with the InnoSetup sample EXEs and ran it on a WinXP SP3 machine and it did not give any error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Supplement to Dan's answer that wouldn't fit in a comment...

For the wizard image files, I tried pretty much every possible permutation of color depth and operating system (Windows 7 and Windows XP) using GIMP 2.8 as the image editor. I came up with the following results:

<s>It doesn't matter what color depth you use; 8-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit or 32-bit. Which makes sense when you think about it, because Windows XP does have support for 32-bit icons on the desktop.</s>  **see edit below**

Dan nailed it on the head when he talked about the 'corrupt' header in the bitmap. It turns out that it is not corrupt. By default, GIMP 2.8 saves 'color space information' in the header of the bitmap file. Innosetup or Windows XP (I'm not sure which) doesn't know how to properly interpret this information.

The key is to make sure that this color space information is **not** saved in the bitmap file. When exporting a bitmap from GIMP 2.8, you have the option to check the 'Do not write color space information' option as shown in the image below.

[image]

**EDIT** 2014-Mar-20

Some updated information:  In InnoSetup version 5.5.4 (running and installing on Windows 7 64-bit OS), using the above method with 32-bit images gives a `bitmap image is not valid` error when the compiled install file is run.

Changing to a 24-bit image, still without the color space information, resolved the issue.

Comment: Found that if this checkbox is checked, Gimp write a BITMAPV4HEADER instead of a BITMAPINFOHEADER. This kind of header should be supported by Windows since Windows 95, so it must be a bug in InnoSetup.

Comment: I was getting a "Floating point division by zero" error when loading one particular bitmap (but not another) into a TQRImage within a Delphi application I was developing in Windows XP. Your answer was incredibly helpful in getting to the root of the issue, as the difference between the two images was that the former had "color space information" included, whilst the latter didn't. Plus I already use GIMP 2.8, so the solution was easy to implement. Many thanks!

Comment: Version 5.5.7 of Innosetup was released on 2015-Dec-28.  This version supports 32-bit bitmaps with alpha channel transparency.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the problem was the WizardImageFile and WizardImageFileSmall.  Was originally using 24bit bmp files.  I reduced the bit depth to 16 and now the setup will work under windows xp. This also made my install package smaller so win win.

Comment: It turns out the the bitmap header on the file I was using was corrupt.  I used gimp to create the bitmap.  If I used paint it seemed to work.

Comment: Dan, thanks for getting me on the right path.  This post saved me hours of frustration.  Of course, it also caused me hours of empirical research as shown by my answer below, but that's just because I don't know when to let go. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [netpbm tools](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) to convert to a bmp. ie from png:

`pngtopnm icon.png | ppmtobmp - > icon.bmp`

The answers above seem correct, unfortunately I ended up wasting a lot of time before I found them  - and I could swear I had tried to tick gimp's "no colourspace" box. And so this is what I ended up doing instead, which can be scripted to convert many icons, and may also help someone facing the same issue.